# External sorting in PHP for large files

Tags: php, sorting, external-sorting

I know similar questions have been asked but they don't address the finer details and not in PHP...

I have a .txt file with a comma separated list of numbers.It's simple enough to sort the file, split it and save into multiple smaller files. What would be an memory efficient way to put small chunks of these files back together and sort them?

All my current attempts to do this have resulted in huge memory utilisation.

A more specific way to put it could be:

1. how do I stream small pieces of data from a file
2. track which pieces of data I've already processed
3. Create a buffer, and when the buffer is full write it out
4. start back at 1 and repeat until all the data has been sorted

Comment: how big is the data?

Comment: Do you really can't use database ? (ex : MySQL) and sort with querry ? You can add a hudge csv (.txt with comma separator) with php + mySQL (look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html). I can help you if you use that :)

Comment: @Xenofexs No databases =[

Comment: @YeLwinSoe Theoretically in the GBs (it has to scale well).

Comment: Then you would have GBs in your memory and in the best case near your file, but PHP isnt made for such a job. To import it in a Database is the way to go or to use another language.

Comment: It would be very slow if you dont cache your file... i mean very slow... 500k lines = 500k starts to read your file until the line is found...